# If you rewrite Boltzmann's entropy formula: $ S = k_B \ln \Omega = \int_1^{\Omega}\frac{1}{t}dt$, what does $t$ represent?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

Since logarithms can be written in the following way:

$$\ln{x}=\int_{1}^{x}{\frac{1}{t}\ dt}$$

for $x\geq1$, I was wondering if you can rewrite Boltzmann's entropy formula in the same way and what the resulting variable is.

$$ S = k_B \ln \Omega = \int_1^{\Omega}\frac{1}{t}dt$$

What does $t$ physically represent?

Comment: This is just a mathematical transformation - it doesn't mean that $t$ represents any valuable physical quantity. I suggest adding to the question the description of the context where you encountered this formula and how it is used there.

Comment: There is no context of this formula I just thought about it and that you could write it in this way.

Answer (score 1):

I will preface my answer with saying that I don't see much utility in this reasoning but here it goes.

We have:
$$S = k_B \log(\Omega) = k_B \int_1^\Omega \frac{1}{\nu} d\nu $$

However, microstates are discrete. Thus, instead of writing $\log$ as an integral I will now use harmonic numbers:
$$ H_N = \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{n} = \log(N)  + \gamma + O(N^{-1}),$$
where $\gamma$ is the Euler-Mascheroni constant $\gamma \approx 0.577$.

For large $\Omega$ we can neglect the constant and the vanishing corrections. We arrive at:
$$S \approx k_B \sum_{n=1}^\Omega \frac{1}{n}, $$
which is a nice formula but I'm not sure about it's usefulness.

You can look at it as a visualization of how additional microstates give diminishing increases in entropy, meaning that going from $\Omega -1$ to $\Omega$ will only increase entropy by $k_B \frac{1}{\Omega}$. With this insight you can look back onto the integral formula. The interpretation is pretty much the same but now you have an integral over a kind of 'continuous number of microstates' $\nu$.

Hope this answers your question

Comment: Thank you very much for providing a clear answer.